# Keyboard taking to hidden model form

Tags: cordova, ratchet-2, ratchet-bootstrap, push.js

When click on input the key board shows next option to reach hidden form, and also able to type something and it will appear when open the model.

The issue is that I can type in to the model form without opening it

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Add readonly into hidden form

Comment: @Hanh Le readonly shouldn't allow to type anything :(

Comment: Do you make sure form is really hidden when search input focus. You can remove attribute readonly when show form and add again when hidden(it not good solution, but you can try it or anything). When form hidden then all input will lost focus. i don't known what happen with your form.